# display pdf output in a separate window

Tags: texstudio

I am using TeXstudio. Because the monitor size is quite small on my laptop, so I have been stacking the pdf output window on top of the LaTeX editor window and switching them back and forth.

This morning when I opened TeXstudio, I suddenly found that pdf output is imbedded in the right side of the TeX Editor window. Since the fonts are so small, I can barely see the pdf output anymore.

Is there a simple way to revoke to what I have before?

Best-
mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the toolbar over the pdf, there should be a button "Windowed Viewer" (second from left in the image). This will move the pdf back into a separate window.

[image]

In case your current view is to small to see the button, try `View->Show embeded PDF large` to fill the whole screen.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Now I learned how to toggle the display of pdf window.  Best